# UICollectionView reloadSections vs reloadItems at indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on an `NSInternalConsistencyException` which randomly causing a crash on my UICollectionView `reloadItems`. What is the difference between reloadSections and reloadItems in terms of performance and in detail of how it actually works?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the two methods? What part aren't you clear on?

Comment: In terms of performance, or if it will solve the `NSInternalConsistencyException` crash

Comment: The error is because you are not updating your data model properly before calling one or more of the `reload...` methods. Performance is not a deciding factor in your choice. Using the correct method based on what needs to be reloaded is the deciding factor.

Comment: I see. But how true is it that when reloadItemsAtIndexPaths, the whole datasource is checked, not only the item count in the desired section? I was thinking if that is the case then I should only use reloadSection.

Comment: If you only need to reload one row, why reload the whole section? Or if you need to reload two rows, one each from different sections, why reload both sections? Use `reloadItems` when you only need to reload specific rows. Use `reloadSection` when you really do need to reload every row in a section along with its header and footer.

Comment: cause I can't seem to track where the inconsistency in item count happens.

Comment: Redo your question posting relevant code, complete error messages, etc. related to your issue.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you can use reloadItems only if the cell you reloading was not moved (IndexPath before and after animation is the same). What is it, you can't use it for animated cell move.